# Running external program on "identify" on WMS layer?

Tags: qgis, wms

I have a QGIS project with several WMS layers. When I select one of these, the identify-function shows a windows with more information on the feature I clicked. It gets this data from the GetFeatureInfo-request to the WMS. Now I would like to pass a part of that to an external program. All I have found so far is how to do this with actions, but these seem to work only on vector layers.

Is there a way to accomplish this with a WMS layer and its GetFeatureInfo response?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here, are you just wanting to capture the WMS GetFeatureInfo requests that are made manually, or do you want to programmatically capture that data.  You mention such requests only working on vector layers, but WMS deliver images; are you refering to WMS where the underlying data is vector data?